# Changing the color of one line/stroke of a shape (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, stroke, graphic-styles

I'm new to illustrator.

When I try to shape certain objects for a 2D cartoon character like the nose, for example, I want it to make the outer part of a nose one color while the color of the inner part of the nose matches the skin.

Or if I make a triangle and color two sides of a triangle blue while making the remaining one side yellow. How do I that?

Comment: Split the path into 2

Comment: There *may* be ways to accomplish this with a single object, but it's sort of impossible to say without seeing a visual example. And any methods may be *unique* to a *specific* piece of work.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Can you show us an image demonstrating the problem, or what you have tried/what has failed.  It's pretty hard to answer this without seeing how you've made it.

Answer (score 0):

Each shape has it's own color in Illustrator.

You cannot apply 2 colors for different parts of the same shape/object.

In your case, to apply 2 colors, one side of the nose needs to be a separate shape/object from the other side of the nose.

- 3 colors → 3 shapes
- 10 colors → 10 shapes
- 100 colors → 100 shapes